# Why my check answer function gets error message and cannot reach the variable array from other function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, global-variables

```js
var quiz = [
  ["What is Superman's real name?", "Clarke Kent"],
  ["What is Wonderwoman's real name?", "Dianna Prince"],
  ["What is Batman's real name?", "Bruce Wayne"]
];

var score = 0 // initialize score
play(quiz);

function play(quiz) {
  for (var i = 0, question, answer, max = quiz.length; i < max; i++) {
    question = quiz[i][0];
    answer = ask(question);
    check(answer);
  } // end of main game loop  gameOver();
}
}

function ask(question) {
  return prompt(question);
}
```

This is where i get error message from the console log

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
      at check (VM13 novice.js:26)
      at play (VM13 novice.js:16)
      at VM13 novice.js:5
```

```js
function check(answer) {
  if (answer === quiz[i][1]) {
    alert("Correct!");
    score++;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
  }
}
```

Comment: You currently have a `}` with no matching `{`, is the upper code in another block, or is that a typo?

Comment: a good idea is to indent block statements. and see if the curly brackets match.

Comment: Thanks, i notice it now in function quiz() but i still get error message

Comment: `if (answer === quiz[i][1])` - there is no variable `i` in this scope.

Comment: Your `check` function doesnt have access to the `i` variable that is defined in your `play` function

Comment: do you have any recommendations how to fix it?

Comment: @Kristine2018 if you want it to work like this, you could pass the `i` variable to your `check` function as a parameter

Comment: @YSbakker   function check(answer, quiz[i])  << I am not sure if im doing it right syntax wise. Is this what you meant by passing param to check function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is no `i` variable in the scope of your `check` function. If you want to compare the answer you have to know the correct position in the array.

One option is to pass `i` to `check`, which will fix your immediate issue. However, it would be even better if you pass in the expected answer instead - that way `check` does not need to know where the questions and answers are kept. So, in the future you could represent the data differently with less changes needed:

```js
var quiz = [
  ["What is Superman's real name?", "Clarke Kent"],
  ["What is Wonderwoman's real name?", "Dianna Prince"],
  ["What is Batman's real name?", "Bruce Wayne"]
];

var score = 0 // initialize score
play(quiz);

function play(quiz) {
  for (var i = 0, question, answer, max = quiz.length; i < max; i++) {
    question = quiz[i][0];
    //also extract the answer to the question
    expectedAnswer = quiz[i][1];
    userAnswer = ask(question);
    check(userAnswer, expectedAnswer);
  } // end of main game loop  gameOver();
}


function ask(question) {
  return prompt(question);
}

//the function now takes both the user and the expected answers to check them
function check(userAnswer, expectedAnswer) {
  if (userAnswer === expectedAnswer) {
    alert("Correct!");
    score++;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
  }
}
```